# how to keep a running total of a 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays, cumulative-sum

Here is some code I have. I am trying to keep a running total of a 2d array. 
I have a random number generator to generate  a x and y location in a 2d array. the location gets a 2 added to the x and y position and the locations directly below, above, to the right, and to the left get a 1 added there. this can happen multiple time. I need to add up all the values entered into the array.

I cant get the running total to work. im not sure how to add the values entered into the 2d array. does anyone know how to do this?

```
int paintSplatterLoop(int ary [ROWS][COLS])
{
double bagCount,
       simCount,
       totalCupCount = 0.0;//accumulator, init with 0

double totalRowCount = 0, totalColCount=0;

double simAvgCount = 0;
double cupAvgCount;

for (simCount = 1; simCount <= 1; simCount++)
{
    for (bagCount = 1; bagCount <= 2; bagCount++)
    {
        for (int count = 1; count <= bagCount; count++);
        {
            int rRow = (rand()%8)+1;
            int rCol = (rand()%6)+1;
            ary[rRow][rCol]+=2; 
            ary[rRow-1][rCol]+=1; 
            ary[rRow+1][rCol]+=1;
            ary[rRow][rCol-1]+=1;
            ary[rRow][rCol+1]+=1;
        }
        totalRowCount += ary [rRow][rCol];
        totalColCount += rCol;
    }

}
totalCupCount = totalRowCount + totalColCount;
cout<<"total cups of paint "<<totalCupCount<<"\n"<<endl;

 return totalCupCount;
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to say what 'it doesn't work' means. It's also not clear to me at least what 'add the values entered into the 2d array' means. Could you give an example? Maybe this is the nub of the problem

Comment: the running total doesnt work

Comment: Why don't you write a separate function that sums all the array elements instead of keeping a running total?

Comment: So how is the running total wrong? Can you give an example. It's very hard to help without understanding what the program is supposed to do.

Comment: I guess that would also work, but I dont know how to sum different array elements.

Comment: I get a 0 for totalCupCount. when I should get lets say 23. it generates random numbers so I cant tell you an exact number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would sum the contents of your two-dimensional array:

```
int sum_array(int array[ROWS][COLS])
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; ++j)
        {
            sum += array[i][j];
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: that didnt give me the exact results I needed, but it helped me figure out what I was leaving out, and now its working. Thanks!